# Where is directory of my custom plugin(python file) after install in calibre?

Tags: plugins, epub, calibre

I wanna edit my plugin file without install it every time.

I have to install plugin every time to debug it.
So, I have a problem with that and I wanna find it's location and edit it (in Mac or Windows)?
Where is my plugin file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all.
I found the answer.
If you run this code in terminal it will update the plugin ([manual](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/creating_plugins.html#debugging-plugins)):

```
/Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS/calibre-customize -b /path/to/your/plugin/directory
```

or if you have calibre folder on your PATH ENV just:

```
calibre-customize -b /path/to/your/plugin/directory
```

and this is works for Windows too (except the path).